# How to react to deselected Item in FileOpenPickerUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, event-handling, filepicker

I have a problem with my FileOpenPicker-app. If I select an item in my GridView, the item will be added to the FileOpenPickerUI, it works fine. But if I deselect an Item **in the FileOpenPickerUI**, it won´t deselect in my GridView.

So I added the Event:

```
_fileOpenPickerUI.FileRemoved += FilePickerUI_FileRemoved;
```

This is the method:

```
private async void FilePickerUI_FileRemoved(FileOpenPickerUI sender, FileRemovedEventArgs args)
{
   //DO SOMETHIG
}
```

This is the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.provider.fileopenpickerui.fileremoved

How can I react to the deselected item? How can I deselect it in my GridView?

Answer (score 0):

There is no two way binding between the `FileOpenPickerUI` item selection/deselection and `GridView` item selection/deselection. If you can access the GridView's selected item within the `FilePickerUI_FileRemoved`handler, you can explicitly set the `SelectedIndex`property to -1.

Comment: The GridView can contains multiple items und you can select and deselect multiple items. I think to set the SelectedIndex to -1, if you just deselect one item, will not have the desired effect.

Comment: I suppose you then have some kind of relationship between the FileOpenPickerUI and GridView items explicitly defined. For each item you deselect in FileOpenPickerUI, get the corresponding GridView item and remove it from the SelectedItems collection.